# Generate Barcode image from Textbox value

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms

I am using [JsBarcode](https://github.com/lindell/JsBarcode)

I am trying to display a barcode image which was generated from textbox's value.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="JsBarcode.all.js"></script>
    <script>
        function textToBase64Barcode(text) {
            var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            JsBarcode(canvas, text, { format: "CODE39" });
            return canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        }
        function getBarcode() {
            var input = document.getElementById('<%= txtInput.ClientID %>').value;
            document.getElementById("image").setAttribute("src", textToBase64Barcode(input));
        }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <img id="image" />
        <br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtInput" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Show Barcode" OnClientClick="getBarcode()" />
        <br />   
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Problem I have is that the Barcode appears and disappear right away. How do I:

- Keep the image barcode appearing on the page
- Retrieve the image Base64 value in the code behind (so I can save it to a database)

Comment: Move the javascript after the the form, so it runs when all elements are in place

Comment: I moved those `<script>...</script>` to after the `<form>` it still does he same thing - disappears right after it appeared

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The barcode dissapears because when the button is clicked the page performs a postback, even if there is no action associated with the button. You could disable the button but you won't get the base64 string of the barcode in code behind.

So you could do something like this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="JsBarcode.all.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" >
        function textToBase64Barcode(text) {
            var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            JsBarcode(canvas, text, { format: "CODE39" });
            return canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        }
        function getBarcode() {
            var input = document.getElementById('<%= txtInput.ClientID %>').value;
            document.getElementById("image").setAttribute("src", textToBase64Barcode(input));

            //set the base64 value in a hiddenfield so the code-behind can process it on postback
            document.getElementById('<%= HiddenField1.ClientID %>').value = textToBase64Barcode(input);
        }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <img id="image" />
        <br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtInput" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Show Barcode" OnClientClick="getBarcode()" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
        <br />

        <!-- hiddenfield containing the base64 value -->
        <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" />

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And in the code behind:

```
    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //you can now do something with the base64 value
        string base64 = HiddenField1.Value;

        //call the javascript code when the postback is done so the barcode is generated again
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "reloadBarcode", "getBarcode()", true);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't found the solution, you just need to add a `return false;` to your `OnClientClick` to prevent the `PostBack`

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Show Barcode" OnClientClick="getBarcode(); return false;" />
```